# ios multi resolution animation

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

What is the best way deal with different resolutions when making animations with cocos2d?

Would each device and resolution need a different scaled image for every frame?

Meaning that i would need 4 of the same image just different scale?

Is that the most efficient way?

I am creating animations like in the [ray wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would each device and resolution need a different scaled image for every frame?

Yes.

> Meaning that i would need 4 of the same image just different scale?

Yes. If you support standard and Retina iPhone, and standard and Retina iPad.

> Is that the most efficient way?

For you as a developer: yes. If you use the right tools, ie TexturePacker.

Any other way, like scaling up/down images on the fly, those are not real options. One causes performance issues, the other blurry images.

You may be able to re-use some of the iPad images for Retina iPhone if you design them to be images where the user might only see 960x640 pixels of a 1024x768 image.